# What keeps this application with a Promise and a resolve invocation from exiting?

Tags: javascript, websocket, promise

This application continues running until I exit it manually with `Ctrl+C`. `I am resolved` is printed in the console. What keeps the application from exiting?

consumer:

```
let client = require('../client');


(async function basicFunctionCheck() {
    try {
        await client.createConnection('ws://127.0.0.1', '8080');
    } catch (error) {
        console.dir(error);
    }
})();
```

provider:

```
let WebSocket = require('ws');

function createConnection(host, port) {
    function close() {
        socket.terminate();
    }

    const socket = new WebSocket(`${host}:${port}`);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        socket.onopen = function () {
            connection = {
                close: close
            }

            console.log('I am resolved');
            resolve(connection);
        };
    });
}

exports.createConnection = createConnection;
```

Comment: I figured I that I need to close the connection for the application to exit. I don't know why or through what mechanism that is at this time. If someone wants to provide more details in an answer, feel free to do so.